# How to use the AND operater in javascript within an XSLT document

Tags: javascript, xslt

I've got a script in an XSL document and it's throwing an error when I try and use the javascript AND operator (&&).

```
if (input1=="" && input2==""){
    alert ("test");
}
```

The error that comes up is: ***XML Parsing Error: not well-formed*** and it points to the && operator.

How can I get around this?

Comment: I think you have to used `&amp;`: `input1=="" &amp;&amp; input2==""`.

Comment: have you considered defer="true" in your script tag?  <SCRIPT LANGUAGE="javascript" DEFER="true">

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are writing XSLT then you are writing an XML document and your XSLT code needs to be well-formed XML. So either escape the ampersands as `&amp;&amp;` or use a CDATA section

```
<script><![CDATA[
if (input1 == "" && input2 == "") { 
  alert("test"); 
}
]]></script>
```

If you are trying to create HTML or SVG with script elements in your XSLT then of course a third option is to make use of external scripts e.g. to put your Javascript code into a `.js` file and to reference it as `<script src="file.js"></script>`, that way you don't have to take any efforts to escape script code according to XML rules.